How to prevent Chromium from accessing other URL's in kiosk mode?
I'm trying to setup a touch kiosk that shows only one website. This means I have a website being served on localhost, and users should not be able to browse to different URL's.
For example, I want to prevent all access to public websites like https://somewebsite.tld/, such that if the user clicks on a link, it will not redirect to that site.
My current script to run chromium looks like this:
chromium \
--no-first-run \
--fullscreen \
--kiosk \
--disable \
--incognito \
--noerrdialogs \
--no-experiments \
--disable-translate \
--disable-pinch \
--disable-infobars \
--disable-features=TranslateUI \
--disable-features=AutofillAssistant \
--overscroll-history-navigation=0 \
--use-gl=desktop \
--disk-cache-dir=/dev/shm/cache/ \
--user-data-dir=/dev/shm/user_data/ \
--proxy-server="0.0.0.0:0" \
--proxy-bypass-list="localhost" \
--app="http://localhost:8000"
http://localhost:8000

Sadly, this does not prevent chromium from opening https://somewebsite.tld/. Does anyone know what I could do other than that
Here is some information about the system I use:

Chromium 120.0.6099.224 built on Debian 11.8, running on Debian 11.10.
Touch display connected to a Raspberry Pi.
the --proxy flag is only to prevent the users from accessing other web pages. Chromium still goes to the "No Internet", making the kiosk unusable.
Not sure what the --app in combination with --kiosk does.


Not anything built into Chromium itself that I'm aware of to block navigation. You probably want to look into kiosk tools with some more features. I've seen this done with a chromium extension or as simple as a python script to restart chromium if it navigates to a different url

This question is similar to: Can I lock a user to one site only in Chrome?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
